# Does .NET's LinkedList recycle nodes?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, garbage-collection, linked-list

When using the overloads which directly accept your data (i.e. `linkedList.AddFirst(myData)` and `linkedList.RemoveFirst()`), does .NET internally recycle its link nodes?

Or would this need to be accomplished manually with a Queue?

Comment: Mind if I ask, why do you need to recycle the nodes?

Comment: Even if it could prove that it was possible to re-use the node (it is not) why would you want to?  The possible gains are almost certainly more expensive than whatever computations would be done in trying to figure out if it could be reused.

Comment: I think that it would be quite easy to create a little pooling mechanism using a queue and then instantiating nodes when the queue is empty: `linkedList.AddFirst(NodePool.Spawn(myData));`. I need an allocation-free sorting algorithm with reasonable performance, so I am thinking insertion sort with a linked list. And then recycle unwanted nodes with something like `NodePool.Despawn(unwantedNode);`.

Comment: I would recommend using DotPeek (http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to decompile source to find out how it works

Comment: Here is a super quick implementation which seems to work perfectly. I haven't profiled or written unit tests yet, but for anybody interested: https://gist.github.com/rotorz/febc8c8b3a8a09f3c3f3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, nodes are not recycled.

As you can see from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs#b99d0011f4fee45a), new nodes are created when new data is added.

```
public LinkedListNode<T> AddFirst(T value) {
    LinkedListNode<T> result = new LinkedListNode<T>(this, value);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I had no idea about that reference source website. Thanks for the link :D

Comment: @LeaHayes No prob. The source has been available for download for a long time, but [this new browsable version is pretty recent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/02/24/a-new-look-for-net-reference-source.aspx).